# Bibliography: Displaying the co-author in the form:surname, initials firstname

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

How can I change my bibliography to this form:

> surname, initials of first name; surname, initial firstname (co-author)

e.g.:

> Jones, F.; Hare, A. (2010)...

instead of

> Jones, F and A. Hare (2010)..

My Code:

```
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,sorting=nyt, firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\medskipamount}
\bibliography{Quellen.bib}
```

It works perfectly for the first author, but not for the co-author.
What can I do?
(I am new here, please excuse the clumsy question)

Answer (score 4):

For the name format, put

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```

in your preamble. This will instruct biblatex to use a "plain" format where the last name always comes first instead of the "last-first/first-last" that it normally uses.

To have semicolons between all multiple names

```
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

Comment: Vielen Vielen Dank

Comment: @Kate Please stuck to English and don't forget to upvote and accept answers which helped you. This is the way to say thank you on this page. Thank you!